# Notion of a non linear orthogonal basis (basis is not an appropriate word here)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In an orthogonal basis, a vector $U$ is expressed as a linear combination of basis vectors. The coefficient $a_i$ of each basis vector $V_i$ in the linear combination, is determined by the inner product of the vector with the corresponding basis vector. Hence each vector $U$ is uniquely determined by the coefficients $a_i, i = 1,2,3...$. In case of an infinite dimensional case, the linear combination of $N$ vectors tends to $U$ as $N \to \infty$.

Consider this modification to the above concept, everything remaining same, The combination alone just not being linear! Given $V_i, i = 1,2,3...$, the $a_i$ being the same as above, (that is taking innerproduct of basis vector with the given vector to get the corresponding coefficient $a_i$), but the final combination of $V_i,i = 1,2,3,...N$ using $a_i,i = 1,2,3,..N$ is just not linear but some a certain nonlinear way using $N$ coefficients.

My question is that is there any such notion/concept used anywhere, especially in an $N \to \infty$ case, anywhere?

**The space under consideration is not a normed space, but has a different metric for notion of distance.**